# How can I replace \' in a file?

Tags: php

How can I replace the 2 special chars ' in a text using php?
I have tried:

```
$file_contents = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
$file_contents = str_replace('Devo "cambiare" l\'Episodio', 'Con "questo" Episodio', $file_contents);
file_put_contents($path_to_file,$file_contents);
```

but it doesn't work because it doesn't read me the ' character and can't find it in the text.
I have tried `\\\'` but it doesn't work.
How can I change the special string in 100 files with php?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What error or other unexpected behavior did you observe?

Comment: `'Devo "cambiare" l\\\'Episodio'`

Comment: I mean it doesn't work because it doesn't replace them. If i put \\\' it doesn't replace it

Comment: I cannot reproduce with `\\\'`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use preg_replace.

syntex : preg_replace('special characters want to replace', 'replace with', input string);

[Read more about preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

Your string placement is not correct, first correct it, Your use of single and double comma is confusing, make it clean.

You can also use str_replace.

```
$file_contents = "abc \\\Episodio xyz";
$data = str_replace('\\\Episodio', 'Episodio', $file_contents);
```

Comment: preg_replace('\'Episodio', '"Episodio', $file_contents); or preg_replace('\\\'Episodio', '"Episodio', $file_contents); doesn't work. It said me Warning: preg_replace(): No ending delimiter ''' found or Warning: preg_replace(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

Answer (score 0):

```
// $replacements = ['from' => 'to', ...]
$file_contents = strtr($file_contents, $replacements);
```

Use `strtr(string_original, array $replacements)`, another point here when using files parsing is thinking about memory when parsing a large file.

Reference: [strtr](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php)

Comment: with this -> $replacements = ['\'' => '"']; $file_contents = strtr($file_contents, $replacements); it doesn't work, page became empty

Comment: here is an example of what you want to do : https://3v4l.org/1rSUG (hope this help you)